# Why does typescript show an error on this scenario with a union type?

Tags: typescript

On this scenario:

```
type Type = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
} | {
    a: number;
    b: number;
};

const func = ({a, b}: Type): string => {
    if (typeof a === 'string') {
        return b;
    }

    return 'w/e';
}

func({a: 1, b: 'w/e'});
```

I get an error on `return b;` stating

> Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

From what I understand by the error, Typescript interprets the Type type as

```
type Type = {
    a: string | number;
    b: string | number;
};
```

, but even if that is the case, why can't I call the `func` function with a string and a number?

The error on the call states

> Argument of type '{ a: number; b: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type'.
>
> Type '{ a: number; b: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; b: number; }'.
>
> Types of property 'b' are incompatible.
>
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

(ts version: 4.7.2)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8BQUNQIYC4oGdgAnASwDsBzAbnUwCM9DTKaBfKAHxVo1yjICuAWzoQiNTFAb9ho8alY1UAYwD2ZQlABmAssqhIAFMiwAaKazxxIASkbFyFAwD5ukklqiHQkVZ6wGCEgA5EyOwTZukphEEMACRGRSEpisqDxQsfGJUMEA7gD0EMFs6Tp6xnwAjObS%20UXBrDZUQA)

- Edit after [UnholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878796/unholysheep)'s comment:

The function call with the wrong types was just to test my hypothesis on why I get the previous error. Why do I get an error at `return b;` is what I don't understand.

Comment: No, it does not interpret it as a union like you think. You have two different options, either 2 `number` or 2 `string` - yet you are trying to call the function with a mix of 1 `number` and 1 `string` which you did not allow with your `Type`

Comment: I agree! The function call with the wrong types was just to test my hypothesis on why I get the previous error. Why do I get an error at `return b;` is what I don't understand.

Comment: is there a reason you're checking if `typeof a === 'string'` and not `typeof b === 'string'`?

Comment: @coglialoro I have used the code above as an example for my case.
The actual project is more complex, but the problem is the same.

In my case the properties of an object's type depend on another property's type.

So, I have to check that specific property and its type, in order to assume the other properties' types. 

What I want to avoid in the end is having to check each property's type and instead check one of them.

Comment: Try `(obj: Type): string => { if(typeof obj.a === 'string') { return obj.b; } ... }` instead. The test narrows the type of `obj` which in turn narrows the type of `obj.b`.

Comment: @kaya3 the error remains :( (ts version: 4.7.2)

Comment: A common pattern is to use discriminated unions, those are made by having a property whose value it's different for each subtype, something like this: [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8BQUNQCYEsDOAxgFxQBEewATjgHYDmp6mAhiRdfQNxMYBGbVWnW4BfKAB8UPbPmJkaAVwC2vCJUaYorKIpVrum-juWrKo7qgIB7GhSgAzBTQJQkACmS5CAGi2-eIiRwkACUAhx0rgB8Upo49lBuXi4IqWTsQqQhsZqYAPR5UAASatDAABbQ1kpgOAA2alAEzDRQtPaNoJB4UGCUVpCUdSDSmpQQwAqUrbwGmCKo0uOT01AA5ADueRBroouOzh7JJOSC9KS+2mvMa-4ka7xrIiHcBwRHsie6phdaJABMdygAGZntwgA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the answer is `Discriminated Unions`.
I have to use a discriminant, a common property in each element of the union.
That, discriminant, property:

1. Has to be a primitive type, and
2. Has to have a specific value and not that value's type. e.g. `isPrimary: true`, not `isPrimary: boolean`.

Then I can check for that property's value to assume the other properties' types.

Also, in Typescript versions < 4.6, If i have an object with a type specified as above, If i destructure it, then the new variables are considered independent and I will continue getting an error similar to the initial example. Destructuring works in version 4.6 or higher.

- [Playground example (version 4.6)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8BQUNQJYGcDKwATlgHYDmAXFEQK4QDc6mAhlTkaWYwL5QA%20KJhlwFi5APxUAZswA2OBkKisoJGgFsARhEI9GqAMYB7EuyhSaJA1CQAKZCI7kANMu5U4kAJRsnZGwB8gpjYUlC2jmJkXsEhmIQQwDSEJMqMIdyoSglJKVAA5ADuAPQQ%20TxZFlb2kZxUtBCuKvnsUVAQAB7M6mCyZdxejFUG9ioAjAOMQA)
- [Playground example (version 4.5)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8BQUNQJYGcDKwATlgHYDmAXFEQK4QDc6mAhlTkaWYwL5QA%20KJhlwFi5APxUAZswA2OBkKisoJGgFsARhEI9GqAMYB7EuyhSaJA1CQAKI5oBWVOJACUbDuRsA%20QZmwpKHsnADoRLzI3fwDMQghgGkISKAdHUOZGAO5UJXjE5KgAcgB3AHoIIp5ciytbZAixSmpCOgAaZSoi9iaoCAAPZnUwWUruN0Zag3qVAEZxxiA)

Helpful links:

- [@Austaras's link to Microsoft's post announcing destructuring support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72572401/19312903)
- [Understanding Discriminated Unions](https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/understanding-discriminated-unions-in-typescript-1ccc0e053cf5)
- [Typescript's Singleton types](https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/understanding-discriminated-unions-in-typescript-1ccc0e053cf5)

Thank you [@Austaras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8965298/austaras) and [@coglialoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18235939/coglialoro)

Comment: It's called [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html)

Answer (score 4):

TS cannot track the relationship of `a` and `b` after you destruct them, so they both be inferred `string | number`. TS 4.6 introduced [a limited control flow analysis for destructing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions), which only applies to discriminated union.

Answer (score 1):

In line with the earlier answers, you can make the `discriminant` optional, and with a little tweak in your function, which `set the value of the discriminant at runtime`, you can have the same output.

```js
type Type = {
  __?: 'string',
  a: string;
  b: string;
} | {
  __?: 'number',
  a: number;
  b: number;
};

const func = (data: Type) => { // const func: (data: Type) => string
  data.__ = typeof data.a as Type['__']
  if (data.__ === 'string') {
    return data.b;
  }
  return 'w/e';
}

const test1 = func({a: 'hello', b: 'w/e'}); // const test1: string
const test2 = func({a: 1, b: 2}); // const test2: string
const test3 = func({a: 1, b: 'w/e'}); // const test3: string | Argument of type '{ a: number; b: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type'.
```